# SQL - Parse String

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that contains:

```
ID     Names 
1      Aaron, Betsy, Cindy 
2      Dillon, Eric, Fred
```

I would like to parse through the name column and have it return:

```
ID   Names 
1    Aaraon 
1    Betsy 
1    Cindy 
2    Dillon
```

I have found several functions online that parse the names column but does not tie the ID back to it.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't already have a one-to-many relationship modeled? Or is this query part of your plan to migrate to a proper one-to-many relationship?

Comment: what rdbms you are using? mysql? oracle? sql server?...

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: When confronted by problems like this and there isn't a function in the rdbms you are using, you can either write that function yourself or bring the result set into your client program and post-process the results locally. For small data sets, I sometimes reach for the latter since it can be simpler.

Comment: What's the example that you found that returns the names but not the id?

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, this query will help migrate the data to a proper one-to-many relationship.

Comment: (oops - hit enter to quick!).  I am using SQL 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
;with cte (id, name, names) as
(
  select id,
    cast(left(names, charindex(',',names+',')-1) as varchar(50)) name,
         stuff(names, 1, charindex(',',names+','), '') names
  from yourtable
  union all
  select id,
    cast(left(names, charindex(',',names+',')-1) as varchar(50)) name,
    stuff(names, 1, charindex(',',names+','), '') names
  from cte
  where names > ''
) 
select id, name
from cte
order by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/edc32/2)

Returns the result:

```
| ID |   NAME |
---------------
|  1 |  Aaron |
|  1 |  Betsy |
|  1 |  Cindy |
|  2 | Dillon |
|  2 |   Eric |
|  2 |   Fred |
```

Comment: @user1411074 Happy to help.  If this answer is helpful to you then be sure to accept via the checkmark on the left. It will help future visitors to the site and you get reputation for accepting.